# Adding nodes to MAAS server

Tags: maas

I was able to install MAAS server using ubuntu 12.04. Then boot up nodes from he PXE. Then installed maas-precise-x86-64-commissioning through pxe.

Now the installation is done. but im unable to commission with the MAAS server. It does not show it as a node and neither im unable to add it manually and end up with following error.

Also what is the default username password for maas-precise-x86-64-commissioning. Im unable to login.

This error when adding node manually.

```
==========================================================================
ERROR 2012-11-20 08:32:54,500 maas.maasserver ################################ Exception: timed out ################################
ERROR 2012-11-20 08:32:54,501 maas.maasserver Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/vary.py", line 22, in inner_func
    response = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/resource.py", line 166, in __call__
    result = self.error_handler(e, request, meth, em_format)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/resource.py", line 164, in __call__
    result = meth(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/api.py", line 251, in dispatcher
    self, request, request.method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/api.py", line 193, in perform_api_operation
    return method(handler, request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/api.py", line 493, in new
    node = create_node(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/api.py", line 418, in create_node
    return form.save()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/forms.py", line 234, in save
    node = super(NodeWithMACAddressesForm, self).save()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 363, in save
    fail_message, commit, construct=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 85, in save_instance
    instance.save()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/models.py", line 114, in save
    return super(CommonInfo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 570, in save_base
    created=(not record_exists), raw=raw, using=using)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/provisioning.py", line 485, in provision_post_save_Node
    profile, power_type, preseed_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/maasserver/provisioning.py", line 245, in __call__
    result = self.method(*args)
                                                                                                                                                               259,1         93%
    result = self.method(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1294, in single_request
    response = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1030, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
timeout: timed out
```

Comment: Perhaps an issue with the network after MAAS installs the OS it looks like its not able to call back to MAAS. If you do a quick network scan while the node is on the login screen are you able to see it?

Answer (score 1):

You should first enlist the node to MAAS, then do the commissioning.